# Modifying fonts with Gimp

Tags: fonts, gimp

I am using the Papyrus font in a banner and I would like to make the font darker and thicker without going as dark as Papyrus Bold.  Papyrus Bold seems to loose the feel of papyrus which is caused by the "voids" in the font.  Bold reduces those "voids" which gives it a different look.

Is there a way to tweak fonts in Gimp that would allow some modification somewhere between Papyrus and Papyrus Bold?  I have been using Gimp for almost 20 years but have never even considered tweaking fonts.   Or, is Gimp completely the wrong tool for the job?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. It would probably be better to use Inkscape, then you could apply a thin stroke to live editable text, sometimes called a faux-bold effect, although if you do it that way you will probably still lose some of those little holes.

Comment: @BillyKerr  That is very helpful.  I am completely lost in Inkscape but I will have a go at it.

Comment: You can also do that in Gimp: `Layer>Text to path` and `Edit>Stroke path`. You can make a selection from the path to limit the thickening in one direction. But that will also smooth the edges.

Comment: @xenoid  Thank you!  I can see this is a tricky operation.   If I could limit two directions it might have better results.  I may try something else.  I like the look of the font but the weight/contrast could be better when using a background.

Comment: I was able to get this to work.  However, I ended up liking the bold version of the font on a wood background.  The wood provided enough rustic feel that the bold did not detract from that feel.